# Save Listview to SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, listview

New to the whole programing world so I Apologise if this question isn't worth asking.

I'm working on a VB application that Uses File Watcher to scan any path the user selects.

The Results are displayed in a ListView. I Have and "Export" button that I want to send the results to an SQL database once clicked.

The code below works but on outputs:

> System.Windows.Forms.ListView+ListViewItemCollection

I want it to display the results instead.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\David\Documents\Monitor.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Monitor] (Changes) VALUES (@Changes)", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Changes", ListView1.Items.ToString())      
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have to loop through each item in list view and then perform insert for each.

Comment: Please put at least four spaces in front of all your lines of code. It will make it a nicely formatted grey box with courier font

Comment: You are using VB, not c#. Please correct this mismatch in your tagging/posting

Answer (score 0):

You either want your code to be this:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Monitor] (Changes) VALUES (@Changes)", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Changes", "dummy")
ForEach li as ListItem in ListView1.Items
    cmd.Parameters("@Changes").Value = li.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
Next li

End Sub
```

..which will insert all list items to your DB

Or you want this:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Monitor] (Changes) VALUES (@Changes)", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Changes", ListView1.SelectedItem.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Which will insert the selected item

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really couldn't get my head around it. Now I know, I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in taskShowListView.Items)
            {

```
            if (itemRow.Selected == true)
            {

                int taskId = Convert.ToInt32(itemRow.SubItems[0].Text);
                string taskDate = itemRow.SubItems[1].ToString();
                string taskDescription = itemRow.SubItems[2].ToString();

                MessageBox.Show("selected");

                ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem((taskId[0].Text));
                listViewItem.SubItems.Add(taskDate[1].ToString());
                listViewItem.SubItems.Add(taskDescription[2].ToString());
                taskShowListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);

            }



        }
```